# Permission denied, AndroidManifest.xml does not work

Tags: android, permissions

m developing launcher for 2.3.3 via specified STB. And I wrote permissions like

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
```

in AndroidManifest.xml.

While debugging -uninstall/install-, sometimes meet "Permission denied" so i should uninstall/install again and again till got no errors with "Permission denied".

Does anyone get this strange bug? Of course, I **did not edit AndroidManifest.xml at all**.

Comment: Add the details of the permission denied error. Are you sure it is related to the external storage?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not occur during 5 hours in my test, so I couldn't capture that log messages. You know, we can't release this version for commercial. If I get that messages, will paste here. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If while debugging your Device is connected to a PC and

> Enable copy files to/from your computer.

Then you will see this `Permission denied` message.

Comment: Is there guides or discussions for that event? Searching with that abnormal word "permission denied" gives me bad results. (Most of results are about missing permissions in AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: Yes, it starts with loading settings(not sharedpreferences, it load settings from xml files in /mnt/sdcard/*)

Comment: Well actually I don't know where it is documented, but I faced this problem few times.

Answer (score 1):

I have had recently this problem, when I upgraded the targetSdkVersion to 23. The "problem" was the new system of dynamic permissions in Android. See http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this answer will be very helpful to later viewers.